# Symfony 2 acceso base de datos de ms sql server y mysql a la vez

Tags: mysql, sql-server, symfony2, doctrine

trabajo con symfony 2.5, doctrine... necesito acceder a dos bases de datos a la vez: una en mysql en un servidor local  y otra en ms sql server 2008 en un servidor remoto. Cómo configuro las conexiones y los parámetros para acceder a ambos indistintamente? Incluso debo acceder desde un bundle a las dos bases de datos a la vez. Necesito configurar 2 entity managers para cada conexión o con una vasta?

Answer (score 1):

Tendrás que configurar las dos conexiones en tu fichero `config.yml`

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            mysql:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_name%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
            sqlserver:
                driver:   pdo_sqlsrv
                host:     '%database_host2%'
                port:     '%database_port2%'
                dbname:   '%database_name2%'
                user:     '%database_user2%'
                password: '%database_password2%'
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: mysql
        entity_managers:
            mysql:
                connection: mysql
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:  ~
                    AcmeStoreBundle: ~
            sqlserver:
                connection: sqlserver
                mappings:
                    AcmeCustomerBundle: ~
```

**MUY IMPORTANTE** Es necsario que en el campo `mappings` indiques qué entidades pertenencen a cada conexión.

En el controlador, o servicio, cuando vayas a hacer uso del `EntityManager`, tendrás que indicar qué conexión usar. Por ejemplo.

```
<?php
// dentro del controlador
$emMySQL = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('mysql'); 
$emSQLServer = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('sqlserver');
```

En el caso de `mysql`, podrías omitir pasar el nombre de la conexión, dado que la habríamos configurado como conexión por defecto aquí:

```
...
orm:
    default_entity_manager: mysql
...
```

**UPDATE**
Si todas tus entidades están en el mismo bundle, tendrás que configurarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
mysql:
  mappings:
    AppBundle:
      # you must specify the type
      type:     "annotation"    
      # The directory for entity (relative to bundle path)
      dir:      "Entity/MySQL"        
      #the prefix 
      prefix:   "Your\Bundle\Entity\MySQL" 

sqlserver:
  mappings:
    AppBundle:
      # you must specify the type
      type:     "annotation"    
      # The directory for entity (relative to bundle path)
      dir:      "Entity/SQLServer"        
      #the prefix 
      prefix:   "Your\Bundle\Entity\SQLServer"
```

Es posible que tengas que alterar la estructura de directorios/namespaces que tienes ahora mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! Una duda, en el archivo de configuración me pones los bundles que utiliza cada entity manager, en caso de que el bundle AcmeCustomerBundle utilice ambas conexiones... lo pongo en "mappings" en cada entity manager, no genera conflictos cierto?

Comment: No. En tal caso debes configurar convenientemente el fichero de mapeos. He actualizado mi respuesta para añadir esa información. Si la respuesta te ha servido y te ha ayudado, por favor, considera votar y marcar como correcta.